# What should I do if I want to use a dependency and it doesn't support null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to use **Geocoder Dependence** but it does not don't support null safety. Is there any method to use **Geocoder Dependence** in the project?

Here is the error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:geocoder

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Instead of `geocoder`, could you check if `flutter_geocoder` does what you want (which does support null-safety)? Alternative, it seems like there are some recent activity on `geocoder` where `master` branch is now null-safe but has yet to be released: https://github.com/aloisdeniel/flutter_geocoder/issues/68 . There are some description in the link about how to use the `master` version for now.

Comment: Ok, I have added an answer you can accept.

Comment: Already do it Brother.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about? Try refresh your page since my answer should be there.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some recent activity on the `geocoder` package where the version on the master branch is now null-safety compatible but the version has yet to be released on pub.dev. You can check this issue here there are also some suggestion about how to use the master version directly instead of fetching the package from pub.dev:

https://github.com/aloisdeniel/flutter_geocoder/issues/68

Alternative, you can take a look at the `flutter_geocoder` package which seems to be a fork of `geocoder` and does support null-safety according to pub.dev.

And I know, it is confusing that the `geocoder` package does calls its GitHub repository for `flutter_geocoder`. But `flutter_geocoder` and `geocoder` is two different packages on pub.dev with different GitHub projects behind it which both has the same name but is created by different users. :)